# Conditionally adding Items to the Excel ListBox control

Tags: excel, datetime, listbox, datediff, vba

I have Excel data like in the sample shown below and 3 ListBoxes

Example of my spreadsheet:

```
 A          B         C
1423    21-03-16    John
2987    03-03-16    Steve
```

My issue: In my `ListBox2` I would like to only show what is in the A columns only if 14 days have passed the days in column B.

I have this code, but cant get it working

```
     Dim rngToSearch As Range
    Dim rngToFind As Range
    Dim valToFind As Variant
    Dim arrClearList()

    valToFind = TextBox1.Value
   With Worksheets("Data2")
        Set rngToSearch = .Columns("A")
    End With
    Set rngToFind = rngToSearch.Find(What:=valToFind, _
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False)

    If Not rngToFind Is Nothing Then

       Call ClearList(Me.ListBox1)
   ListBox1.AddItem

        With ListBox1
            .List(.ListCount - 1, 0) = rngToFind.Value
            .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = rngToFind.Offset(0, 1).Value
            .List(.ListCount - 1, 2) = rngToFind.Offset(0, 3).Value
            .List(.ListCount - 1, 3) = rngToFind.Offset(0, 4).Value
            .List(.ListCount - 1, 4) = rngToFind.Offset(0, 5).Value

        End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Pertinent to you question in regards to conditionally populating the `ListBox2`: your code snippet does not implement that part. You can add `Items` from Column "A" based on the `DateTime` value in the column "B" as shown in the following VBA code snippet using `DateDiff` function to check the condition you have specified (14 days pass since the date value in Column "B"):

```
Sub AddItemsToListbox2()
Dim I As Integer
Dim maxRow As Integer

maxRow = 100
ListBox2.Clear
For I = 1 To maxRow
    If (DateDiff("d", Now, Range("B" & I).Value) > 14) Then
        ListBox2.AddItem Range("A" & I)
    End If
Next I
End Sub
```

The solution was tested on sample data set shown below (the last item was added to the `ListBox2`):

```
A       B           C   
1423    3/21/2016   John
2987    3/3/2016    Steve
3345    4/28/2016   Anna
```

Hope this may help.

Comment: Thank you for the Alex - Quick question, where exactly should I place this code? Thanks in advance

Comment: You can add it to the same Sub shown in your code snippet, or just call this Sub from that code snippet, e.g. Call AddItemsToListbox2() . Please mark the answer accepted if you are satisfied with the solution. Best regards,

Comment: Unfortunately this didnt work.  My dates a stored in J, so I changed the B value to J but nothing shows up in the listbox. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Comment: The answer is given to your original question, which refers to the dates stored in column B. If you are changing the requirements, then please either make the appropriate editing, or even better - post a separate question. Also, make sure that there are values older that 14 days in your date Column, otherwise nothing will appear in the list. Thanks and regards,